# Seaborn distplot with rugplot from different array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Making a distplot with a rug using seaborn is easy:

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (8, 4)}); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x, rug=True)
```

The rug plot above reflects the distribution `x`.  But what if I want to display the rug from a different distribution, `rug_array`, under the dist plot of `x`?

```
rug_array = np.array([-2.0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2.1, 3])
```

The answer should display a plot of the curve `x` with rug plot ticks at -2,-1, ,0, 1, 2, 2.1, and 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seaborn provides a function [`rugplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html) to draw the rugplot. The idea is to use this function.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(100)
rug_array = np.array([-2.0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2.1, 3])

ax = sns.distplot(x, rug=False)
sns.rugplot(rug_array, height=0.05, axis='x', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Not to make this more complicated, but if rug_array was in a different scale than the current x-axis (eg log10), how could I add a separate axis to match the rug?  I can post this as a different question if need be.

Comment: You can add a new axis with `ax2 = ax.twiny()`, and plot the rugplot to it via `sns.rugplot(..., ax=ax2)`. However, I doubt that the plot will be easily understandable. If this does not help you, posting a new question with an exact problem description might make sense.